# Restrict access to admin/* sites with cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin, cancan

I'm building an app which have two user models: `user` and `user_admin`, `user_admin` is provided with `activeadmin` via `devise` and `user` was created with devise too. I created main page, some resources, and admin page, now I want to restrict access to any admin page via `cancan`. So to summarize:

> 1. User is on main page, then go to same other page, devise redirect him to sign_in
> 2. after sign in user can browse pages, but if he will want to go on /admin cancan should be give him 404 or give access to admin pages
>      only if he has admin role, then he must sign in with another
>      user_admin account.

So how I can describe in `ability` restriction to admin pages, some problems are:
I don't know where is `Admin::DashboardController#index` thus I can't check here role and make redirect to 404
Also Active admin is generating dynamically routes so I can't use that either.

How can I make it working?

Comment: why two models you can use one model and differentiate based on role?

Comment: but by default user cannot signin to active admin, only admin_user